# How can I raise the navigation bar a bit higher

Tags: html, css, navigation

So there's a bit of space between the navigation bar and the banner image. I tried everything and apparently it's not getting fixed. Here's a screenshot of it

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRkkF.png)

I need help as fast as possible since this is a school project

Comment: can you share some css or fiddle?

Comment: Include the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem in the screenshot. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgpptny This is the css of the navigation bar. If that one doesnt work here's another link https://jsfiddle.net/wgpptnyw/2/

Comment: You need to add the HTML of the navbar to the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgpptnyw/4/ I updated the link. Here you go

Comment: The bar works fine on the home page but on the different one it's a little bit down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to raise your navbar a little you can decrease the `margin-top`like the following:

```
.topnav {
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Even if it is not the cleanst way to do it, play with the `margin-top` negative value until you get the desired output.

Comment: You're a legend